# Using AOT and LLVM makes app size too large when installed on the device

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I tried using AOT and LLVM to reduce start up time in my xamarin forms app on android. It really made trick. I had around 10-12secs and now google firebase reports between 2-7secs based on the device as shown below.

[image]

What my settings are as followings;
- Link SDK and User assemblies
- Bundle into native assemblies
- Proguard
- no-write-symbols,nodebug
- Separate Apk for each Abis

Project file for related group looks like as below;

```
 <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <AndroidUseSharedRuntime>False</AndroidUseSharedRuntime>
    <DebugType>
    </DebugType>
    <AndroidLinkMode>Full</AndroidLinkMode>
    <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>true</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
    <AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>true</AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>
    <JavaMaximumHeapSize>1G</JavaMaximumHeapSize>
    <AotAssemblies>true</AotAssemblies>
    <EnableLLVM>true</EnableLLVM>
    <AndroidAotAdditionalArguments>no-write-symbols,nodebug</AndroidAotAdditionalArguments>
    <DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>
    <BundleAssemblies>true</BundleAssemblies>
    <AndroidEnableMultiDex>True</AndroidEnableMultiDex>
    <EnableProguard>true</EnableProguard>
    <Debugger>Xamarin</Debugger>
    <AndroidSupportedAbis>armeabi-v7a;x86;x86_64</AndroidSupportedAbis>
    <AndroidLinkSkip>Akavache;Akavache.Sqlite3;SQLiteNetExtensions;SQLiteNetExtensionsAsync;SQLite.Net;SQLite.Net.Async;Syncfusion.DataSource.Portable;Syncfusion.Data.Portable;Syncfusion.Pdf.Portable;Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.XForms;Syncfusion.SfNumericUpDown.XForms;Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.XForms.Android;Syncfusion.SfNavigationDrawer.Android;Syncfusion.SfNavigationDrawer.XForms;Syncfusion.SfNavigationDrawer.XForms.Android;Syncfusion.SfSchedule.XForms;Syncfusion.SfSchedule.XForms.Android;Syncfusion.SfSchedule.Android;Syncfusion.Compression.Portable;Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.AppIndexing;Xamarin.Insights;Splat;Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement;Xamarin.FireBase.AppIndexing;Xamarin.FireBase.Common;Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm;</AndroidLinkSkip>
    <AndroidEnableMultipleDex>true</AndroidEnableMultipleDex>
    <AndroidExplicitCrunch>true</AndroidExplicitCrunch>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

**PROBLEM;**
App size increased as expected but it is not the Apk size problem for me, rather installed size on device. here are the values.

- APK is 20mb using single apk, settings above but no AOT no LLVM
- APK separate apks per abi are 16mb, settings above but no AOT no LLVM
- single apk 49 mb, , settings above but with  AOT + LLVM
- separate Apks per abi are 26 mb,settings above  with  AOT + LLVM a

Until here, everything seems perfect. I can accept 6mb-10mb increase even it is still so high amount but the difference is installed size of the app on the device. without AOT is around 30mb installs. with AOT+LLVM 100mb+

When I extract the apk, i can see what is in the apk.
Capture below is from lib folder (biggest folder) without using AOT and Bundle into Native assemblies

[image]

Capture for with AOT+LLVVM.. see the yellow highlighteds are indeed what we need to install the apk according to the previous apk. I dont know if I need any extra library to run AOT but why those blue underlined 3rd party libraries are there. they are supposed to be bundled into native assemblies as in the first screenshot. 
Do I understand it wrong or Xamarin has bug on using AOT with Bundles into Native assemblies?

[image]

Comment: No one will answer :(,  this is "terra incognita". I have similar problems. I use AOT (without LLVVM) . This is the only way to "quickly"(5 seconds :( ) start an application.

Comment: @FetFrumos I think that LLVVM doesnt affect the startup time but it is good for general performance. My app starts fast with or without LLVM but I tried packing with both and both have the huge size problem. LLVM increases extra 3 mb on apk but when installed size is almost the same as with LLVVM. So it is huge